# Google map (v3) infowindow opening on the same marker all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I create several Gmarkers (from  JSON data loaded by JQuery "load" function), on all of them I add an event listener to open the infowindow object I created before on the marker, and then I add them all to the map.

The issue is that the infowindow always opens on the same marker.
I all had this working before, i can't see where the problem is... scope of the variable ? stupid mistake somewhere ?

I uploaded an [example](http://stoeffler.cc/maptest/), and here is a [shortcut to the javascript file](http://stoeffler.cc/maptest/map.js)

The code :

```
    var map;
    var infowindow;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.15984,2.329102);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
        scrollwheel: false
      }

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<p>Test</p>'});

        $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {

            var markers = [];
            for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng});

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
              });

              markers.push(marker);
            };

            for (var j = markers.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                markers[j].setMap(map);
            };

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Change

```
infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

to

```
infowindow.open(map,this);
```